# How to replace same instance of string in a string with an array?

Tags: php

```
$replaces = array('replace 1', 'replace thing 2', 'third replace');

$string = '{REPLACEME} sfsfsdfsdf {REPLACEME} sdfopjsd {REPLACEME} sdfsdf {REPLACEME}';
```

What is the easiest way to replace each successive `{REPLACEME}` with the matching replace?

If there are more `{REPLACEME}` than replaces, it should not touch the extra `{REPLACEME}`'s.

So the output I would want with my example is:

```
replace 1 sfsfsdfsdf replace thing 2 sdfopjsd third replace sdfsdf {REPLACEME}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foreach($replaces as $rep) {
  $string = preg_replace('~\{REPLACEME\}~',$rep,$string,1);
}
```

Comment: Note that with every iteration of the `foreach` the whole string is searched for `{REPLACEME}`. If your replacement does also contain that string it gets replaced.

Comment: The replacement string is corrupted if it includes a backslash. According to the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/preg-replace), "To use backslash in replacement, it must be doubled". Therefore, in the example `$string` in the above should be `str_replace ('\\', '\\\\', $string)`

Answer (score 2):

this might be a quick idea:

```
$replaces = array('replace 1', 'replace thing 2', 'third replace');
$string = '{REPLACEME} sfsfsdfsdf {REPLACEME} sdfopjsd {REPLACEME} sdfsdf {REPLACEME}';
$sampler = explode('{REPLACEME}',$string);
foreach($sampler as $k=>$v){
 if(isset($replaces[$k])) {
     $sampler[$k] .= $replaces[$k]
 } else {
  $sampler[$k] = '{REPLACEME}' //or whatever
 }
}
$final = implode("",$sampler);
//it's ok for not so long strings or at least not to many {REPLACEME}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Catalin Marin’s proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863863/how-to-replace-same-instance-of-string-in-a-string-with-an-array/4863943#4863943) but without the need to check whether there are enough replacement strings:

```
$parts = explode('{REPLACEME}', $string, count($replaces)+1);
for ($i=0, $n=count($parts); $i<$n; $i++) {
    $parts[$i] .= $replaces[$i];
}
$string = implode('', $parts);
```

If you need a regular expression for the search, you can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) instead of `explode`.

The advantages of this solution in opposite to calling `str_replace`/`preg_replace` multiple times consecutively are:

- `$string` is only searched *once* for occurrences of `{REPLACEME}` (only `count($replaces)` at most)
- `{REPLACEME}` does not get replaced if it appears in a previous replacement of `$replaces`.